# ¿Como eliminar objeto de un arrayList Java Android RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, adapter

El problema esta en que tengo una lista con objeto y quiero objeterlos con su cantidad asignada pero intento usar el remove(objeto) y no hace nada.

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        Button nombre, btnCantidad;
        ImageButton btnMas, btnMenos;

```
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        nombre = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnNombreArticuloDesp);
        btnMas = (ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnMasDesp);
        btnMenos = (ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnMenosDesp);
        btnCantidad = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnCantidadDesp);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.despacho_item, parent, false);

    view.setOnClickListener(this);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Articulo item = list.get(position);

    listDespacho.clear();

    for (int x=0; x < list.size(); x++){
        listDespacho.add(new Despacho_info(1, list.get(x).getId(), 0));
    }

    final List<Despacho_info> despacho_infoList = listDespacho;

    holder.nombre.setText(String.valueOf(item.getNombre()));

    //-----------AUMENTA LA CANTIDA
    holder.btnMas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int cantidadVender = Integer.parseInt(holder.btnCantidad.getText().toString());
            holder.btnCantidad.setText(String.valueOf(cantidadVender+1));

            despacho_infoList.remove(new Despacho_info(1, 1, 0));

            Iterator<Despacho_info> iteratorBand = despacho_infoList.iterator();

            while(iteratorBand.hasNext()){
                if(despacho_infoList.contains(new Despacho_info(1,1,0))){
                    iteratorBand.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    //---------DISMINUYE LA CANTIDAD
    holder.btnMenos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int cantidadActual = Integer.valueOf(holder.btnCantidad.getText().toString());
            if (cantidadActual!=0){
                holder.btnCantidad.setText(String.valueOf(cantidadActual - 1));
            }


        }
    });

    setListDespacho(despacho_infoList);

    //-------------ABRE DIALOGO PARA INTRODUCIR LA CANTIDAD
    holder.btnCantidad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
            final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogo_cantidad, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            builder.setView(view);

            final Button btn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnOKcantidad);
            final EditText txt = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.txtCantidadDialogo);
            txt.setFocusable(true);

            builder.setCancelable(true);
            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

            alert.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            alert.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            alert.show();

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    alert.cancel();
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Alerta Cerrada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    holder.btnCantidad.setText( txt.getText() );
                }
            });
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public List<Despacho_info> getListDespacho() {
    return listDespacho;
}

public void setListDespacho(List<Despacho_info> listDespacho) {
    this.listDespacho = listDespacho;
}

public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

llama a `remove` le indicas la posicion y notificas los cambios:

```
list.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
```